# representing a given maze in java

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence, maze

So, I'm supposed to represent a maze that I've been given a picture of and create a search-algorithm to solve the maze. It seems like an array would be a good way to represent the maze but I'm having real difficulty just understanding how to transfer the different walls of the maze into an array, it just doesn't make any sense to me how to go about doing that? Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: You are receiving down votes as you haven't shown what you have tried, or any code whatsoever, so you appear to be asking someone to do the work for you, as opposed to asking for help, even though your intention is to ask for help in approaching the question. For future posts, try adding in what you have tried, what you have looked at, etc. But otherwise, Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of representing a maze would be to use an array within an array (assuming your maze is 2D and grid format). so for example, if (x) represents a wall and ( ) represents paths your maze might be:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x     x     x
x xx x   x     xxxxx x
x xx x   x           x
x xx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx
```

etc.

So an array within an array implementation would put each row in an array (called columns) and each of those arrays put into another array (called rows).
so the top left corner would be rows[0][0] = x, rows[1][1] = space.

nested for loops would be your best way to doing this method